# Unable to login with correct Username and Password

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, authentication

I have designed a site using asp.net and database sql server. For login there are two roles; "admin" & "User" and several users with the role User. A user is now unable to login even with the correct user id and password. I have checked the tables in database. In the table "aspnet_membership", the field values are chaged as:

```
IsLockedOut=True
FailedPasswordAttemptCount=10
LastLockoutDate=#some date
FailedPasswordAttemptWindowStart=#some date
```

I have changed cthe values to:

```
IsLockedOut=False
FailedPasswordAttemptCount=0   
LastLockoutDate=#default date  
FailedPasswordAttemptWindowStart=#default date
```

But still the user is unable to login.

Do I have to change any other value in any table?

Comment: Are they using the right password. 10 lockouts means that they didnt know it before...

Comment: I think they used a wrong password. But i saw the password from the table and tried to login and failed

Comment: Doesn't your user password contain some interesting characters, like trailing or non-breaking spaces?

Comment: no........ the password is a simple word.

Comment: What is the *actual error message* you're getting? "Unable to login" can be anything from invalid credentials to not having access to the correct database to the building being on fire.

Comment: The Error Message is" **Your login attempt was not successful. Please try again.** ".The credentials are valid. There are several tables created like: aspnet_Membership,aspnet_Users, aspnet_UsersInRoles,aspnet_SchemaVersions,aspnet_Roles, etc.. Do I have to change any value in any of these tables.